# Is more rudder pressure needed in gliding turns than normal turns

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, faa-knowledge-test

The FAA Airplane Flying Handbook says

> the rudder compensates for yawing tendencies when rolling in or out of a gliding turn; however, the required rudder pedal pressures are reduced as a result of the reduced forces acting on the control surfaces

Forces acting on the control surfaces are reduced. Doesn't it need more rudder pressure (so a greater rudder deflection) to generate more force to counteract the reduced force acting on the control surfaces?

Also one more question: reduced forces acting on the control surfaces mean the glide speed is rather slow (since slower speed means reduce forces acting on control surfaces), right?

Comment: I think what they mean is less forces acting on the ailerons, therefore, you don't need as much rudder to counteract yaw (since the roll is less)

Comment: But if you do want to turn, you do want to achieve the same roll (as in normal fligh), don't you? Then you need to deflect ailerons more. Then the effect of adverse yaw will be greater. Then greater rudder deflection is needed. Am I right?

Comment: Not seeing the passage in the Airplane Flying Handbook in context, it's a bit hard to know exactly what the FAA meant.  More to the point, could you be more clear about what *you* want to know?  You say "Doesn't it need more rudder pressure (so a greater rudder deflection) to generate more force to counteract the reduced force acting on the control surfaces?"-- do you mean compared to a non-gliding (constant-altitude?) turn at the *same* airspeed?  Or compared to a turn at your normal cruise speed?  If the latter, what is the airspeed in the *gliding* turn, i.e. what's the delta involved?

Answer (score 1):

Don't overthink this one.  Power differences affect yawing moments and change rudder input requirements. Torque and P-Factor generally mean more right rudder is required with more power than with less, with the engine turning clockwise out front.

But for your purposes, you are only concerned with keeping the skid ball centered, and knowing those effects is just something you keep in mind to anticipate what to do with your feet.

And that basically comes down to:

1. Applying left aileron, learn to squeeze a bit of left rudder instinctively, then check the skid ball and adjust, "stepping on the ball" with whatever foot is required to keep it centered.  Vise versa for right aileron.
2. Adding power, learn to squeeze a bit of right rudder instinctively, then adjust, "stepping on the ball" with whatever foot is required to keep it centered.

In the end, you just do whatever it takes with your feet to try to keep the skid ball centered at all times.

Comment: I was once an admiral, but only fleetingly. One of my captains only stayed at the back of his ship, he was so stern. Another decorated the front of his with bow-ties. The ship of the third somehow shrunk to his size and cap-sized. Eventually they a-mast some followers and threw me overboard - a rudder upsetting experience...

Comment: Are you trying to pun-ish me?  HAR HAR HAR.

Answer (score 0):

Your question may betray a fundamental, (but common) misconception. The rudder is not needed to compensate for yawing tendencies due to ***turns***. It s needed to compensate for yaw due to the displacement of the ailerons needed to ***roll*** the aircraft when ***establishing***, (or rolling out of), the bank angle needed for the turn. So as far as the need for rudder, it doesn't much matter what is going on ***in*** the turn. What matters is how much aileron you use, (how slow or how fast you roll into the bank)